# How to delete debug symbols in static libs

Tags: linker, arm, greenhills

I have four libraries that I wrote in C. Now I want to share these libraries (static libs for example, `libA.a`) with a software developer who will use them to generate a "final" executable.

My question is, how can I delete the debug symbols so that he doesn't find some information about the working process inside my libs?

Thanks in advance.

Development Environment: GreenHills

Compiler: ccarm

Comment: Assuming this is a unix-like os, the `strip` utility removes extraneous gubbins from executables.

Comment: I don't know about your compiler in particular, but every compiler I've used will only generate debug symbols if I specifically requested it via `-g`.

Comment: @NeilButterworth the strip command (in my case it is called gstrip) can only be used to the final executable/binary not to a static library

Comment: Well, in that case, don't compile the libraries with debugging information.

Comment: As a *completely* different approach, make him sign an NDA, and ship him the compiled static libraries, and the source.  I'm a great believer that source access won't actually help people rip you off much, but will help them debug problems.

Comment: The approach with an NDA is not a solution for me but thank you @MartinBonner. How can i compile the libs without debug information?

Comment: @SDE, omit the `-g` compiler flag